What's "Hey, I think you missed a few transactions when you broke out your charges on our credit card bill." mean?
I found a sample sentence in a Farlex Dictionary of Idioms for a definition of the phrase "break out" [which means: "To highlight just one portion or section of something."] that I'm having trouble understanding.

Hey, I think you missed a few transactions when you broke out your charges on our credit card bill.

I googled what a "credit card bill" is and it seems that it's just another word for your "bank statement" that everyone receives at the end of each month THEREFORE it's confusing that he or she is saying "your charges" as if it was a hotel receptionist tallying up the charges for them as a guest.
QUESTION 1. Who is the person speaking and who are they speaking to?
QUESTION 2. What is the general sense of this sentence?

A credit card is very different from a bank account, though both offer very similar-looking payment cards. With a bank account you are spending money you already have, with a credit card you are using money someone else has and promising to pay it back (and more on top for the privilege of using their money).

Exactly - so a credit card bill consists only of sums paid out (charges). Presumably the speaker is one of a couple who share a credit card, speaking to the other one.

"To break out" a sum total is to separate it into subtotals according to some criterion or some set of criteria.   For example, you could break out total spending for 2023 by arbitrary categories (food, travel, entertainment, clothing, rent, medical, etc) or by payee, or by date of transaction, whatever. It is not merely a highlighting but the application of a particular filter or set of filters in order to divide a lump amount into informative subtotals.

In light of how "break out" is normally used, it's not clear to me who is being spoken to in that sentence.  Normally a merchandise vendor would not have access to a customer's credit card statement, though they would be able to identify charges against the customer's card that they initiated when the  customer used the card to purchase something from them.

The conversation involves two people who are sharing a credit card account. The situation is that when the bill comes, they determine which of them made each purchase. One of them then pays the bill to the bank, and the other reimburses the first one for their share of the charges.
The person speaking seems to be the one who will pay the bill, they're speaking to their partner. "break out your charges" refers to the process of determining the purchases that the partner made. And the first person is complaining that they omitted some purchases they were responsible for.
